# error CS0111: Type 'Program' already defines a member called 'Main with the same parameter types c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAxQv.png)
when i run me code
this eroor show up
error CS0111: Type 'Program' already defines a member called 'Main' with the same parameter types

Comment: You probably have some other main program code in any of the project's .cs files. This would also be the case if you have code outside of any methods.

Comment: first error says you already have `Program`

Comment: Please include the full code and the error message as *text* - both code and errors are inherently text, and it's much easier to help you if we can see that text as text in the question. Aside from anything else, it lets us copy and paste the code to try to reproduce the error ourselves.

Comment: I *suspect* you want to delete `tempCodeRunnerFile.cs`...

Comment: There is not other program

Comment: @Waswasane: Well there's `tempCodeRunnerFile.cs` - I strongly suspect that has another program. Did you check it? Is that file *meant* to be there?

Answer (score 0):

The error is for tempCodeRunnerFile.cs. It must have `Main`. Program.cs already does. And they both seem to be in same project. It would make sense. I get error even in VS 2019 if two files have Main() in the same project.

**Based on update by OP**
Please remove One of the `Main` or include only one file in csproj.

Comment: so what i do to fix