# Mysterious "Main" Method

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a WPF app (.Net Framework 4.8) with VS 2022 Community Edition on Windows 11. I removed the StartUpUri from App.xaml, and added a `[STAThread] public static void Main()` in App.xaml.cs. Just like with another such up originally written with VS 2019 on Windows 7 which also works with VS 2022 and Windows 11.
But now when I compile, I get the error message

3>C:\some path\obj\Debug\App.g.cs(69,28,69,32): error CS0111: Type 'App' already defines a member called 'Main' with the same parameter types

According to [another question with a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68234899/error-cs0111-type-program-already-defines-a-member-called-main-with-the-same) with VS Code, a file named `tempCodeRunnerFile.cs` should be deleted. But it does not exist on my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the `obj` folder, you can find the autogenerated `App.g.cs` which will indeed contain a `Main` method.

I would suggest creating a separate `Program` class, writing your `Main` method there, and then specifying the `StartupObject` property in your project file to be the `Program` class (with the appropriate namespace). That way there's no ambiguity between your code and the generated code.

There *may* be a build property you can specify to stop it from generating the `Main` method, but personally I find it's usually harder to find that sort of thing than just avoid it being a problem.

Comment: Thanks, creating a Program.cs file with the Main method and setting that as the startup does the trick. Still odd that the simpler method worked in the other project...

Comment: @BernhardHiller: My *guess* is that your earlier project was based on .NET Framework, whereas the new one was based on .NET 6 or .NET 8.